# Liaison après l'auxiliaire de conjugaison « avoir »

Tags: liaisons, auxiliaires

Les informations suivantes sont contradictoires. Quelle est la règle que l'on doit suivre ?

> ([Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/20a.html#2))
> Liaisons facultatives
> Liaisons facultatives dans le groupe verbal
> un peu moins fréquente après avoir
> • j’avais‿écouté, ils ont‿entendu.

> ([La Liaison](https://www.francoisenore.com/articles/la-liaison))
> liaison obligatoire
> avoir ou être + participe passé
> • Ils ont adoré le spectacle - Nous sommes arrivés à l'heure.

Comment: La GGF (donc 21e s.) dit qu'elle est possible, idem pour Le Robert qui la dit facultative, *Le Bon Usage* de 1975  dit qu'a la 3e pers du sing. (donc pas aux autres) elle se fait toujours. Mais [trouvé en ligne](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/liaisons/)  que *Le bon usage* 13e edit. (donc 94) ne la met plus qu'en « recommandé » pour ces mêmes 3e personnes.  Comme quoi la langue bouge et les « règles » ne reflètent que des états éphémères.  Facultatif aussi pour la BDL. D'après mon expérience Kalmbach est une ressource plutôt  sérieuse.

Comment: Si une "réponse" consiste à aligner ce que disent GGF, BDL, LBU, ... l'auteur de la question devrait faire ça lui-même en tant que recherche préliminaire...

Comment: @None On peut alors conclure qu'il y a plusieurs écoles et qu'on ne peut parler ni de liaison facultative ni de liaison obligatoire. C'est une situation qui mène à une nouvelle catégorie (liaisons incertaines ou quelque chose dans ce genre).

Comment: @Frank 1-  Je n'ai pas fait de réponse. 2- La GGF n'est accessible que dans sa/une bibliothèque ou en abonnement payant, pas facile d'y avoir accès pour tout le monde, je partage donc ma ressource, idem pour  *Le Bon Usage*, bien que souvent cité en ligne, il n'est pas officiellement accessible librement. Seul la BDL est une ressource librement accessible (et que je considère "sérieuse").

Comment: @None je critiquais plutôt l'auteur de la question que ta réponse, qui est très bien, et aussi je voulais faire réfléchir sur la nécessité de _références_ sur FSE: bien sûr, une référence peut être utile, mais je ne sais pas si un FSE où les questions/réponses ne seraient qu'un long échange de "références" serait le but. On peut probablement répondre à la plupart des questions avec un bon moteur de recherche...

Comment: @LPH Tu conclues ce que tu veux. Je ne me reconnais pas dans ton « on ». Et il n'y a pas pour moi non plus de « liaisons incertaines ». Il y a juste une liaison que certains font et pas d'autres, et dire qu'elle est interdite est à mes yeux trompeur. LBU introduisait « recommandé » en 94, je ne sais pas ce que dit la dernière édition.

Comment: @Frank J'avais bien compris ton propos, mais on ne trouve pas tout en ligne (ou plutôt on trouve tout et n'importe quoi).  Certaines références sérieuses peuvent être utiles.

Comment: @None Tout à fait d'accord, pas de problème. Je persiste à penser que les liaisons sont un sujet épineux dans bien des cas, où ceux qui pratiquent la langue tous les jours peuvent faire ou ne pas faire telle ou telle liaison, en dehors de régionalismes possibles (qui existent aussi!). Et je continue à penser que dans bien des cas, faire ou ne pas faire certaines liaisons ne dérange aucunement, et n'est peut-être même pas remarqué. Il n'y a pas toujours de "règle" pour les liaisons ni toujours de classification en "obligatoire" et "interdit".

Answer (score 2):

Le classement proposé dans la page "[La liaison](https://www.francoisenore.com/articles/la-liaison)" fait preuve d'un prescriptivisme surprenant de la part d'une licenciée en lettres et docteure en linguistique.

Un très grand nombre des liaisons rapportées comme étant obligatoires<sup>1</sup> sont parfois, voire souvent, non réalisées.

> Toulon es**t u**ne belle ville  [5:11](https://youtu.be/uPrjlv-QP7E?t=307)  [0:18](https://youtu.be/09wEf2vXCiE?t=18)
> Vous ête**s i**diot  (vous êtes isolés) [25:09](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoxME6AeG1g&t=1507s)
> Il es**t é**vident [10:04](https://youtu.be/nEfZnvs13vQ?t=600) [1:54](https://youtu.be/-Bh_exMKMSQ?t=110)
> C'es**t à** voir  [10:40](https://youtu.be/7sFVlJ-K4JE?t=639)
> Ils on**t a**doré  [1:32](https://youtu.be/_3wP4rQOYZo?t=92)
> Nous somme**s a**rrivés [13:00](https://youtu.be/3ggF2jE5d8M?t=776)
> Des gen**s heu**reux [24:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJpz-z2xiK8&t=1460s)
> Quan**d i**l est là  [11:57](https://youtu.be/pie2qtEUpKs?t=708)
> *mai**s au**ssi* [0:39](https://youtu.be/zPn7Tm4CAEE?t=31)
> *tro**p é**troite* [3:59](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfAk5QVRap0&t=236s) [6:43](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8D1ZSnnR1k&t=400s)
> *Pa**s u**ne*  [17:43](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPn7Tm4CAEE&t=1050s)
> *Pa**s en**core* [26:36](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYjbFx4SIq0&t=1590s)
> *Pa**s au**jourd'hui* [6:38](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh4PNaT5s3c&t=394s)
> *De hau**t en** bas* [1:56](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t4A96EYuXA&t=110s)
> *Do**s à** dos* [1:11:22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZFT44ZPQ5w&t=4274s)
> *Droi**t au** but* [11:07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K94K6YOR9QQ&t=660s)
> *Mo**t à** mot* [13:24](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKdlIpBmOrA&t=799s)

Quelques liaisons interdites sont à l'inverses parfois réalisées :

> Les points sur le**s i** [40:08](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7DHrWZYcjw&t=2400s)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Obligatoire* est le terme consacré mais il est abusif. Il ne faut pas le prendre au pied de la lettre. Aucune loi ou police n'est là pour imposer ou interdire les liaisons. C'est de l'observation que découlent les classifications et pas de règles gravées dans le marbre.</sub>

Comment: De même pour _interdite_. J'étais surpris de voir cette classification pour les liaisons.